# Compare combination of two column with combination of other two in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, join

I have 2 tables, tbl_NameCode and tbl_Bkp both having columns ID and Name.

I have to select records from tbl_NameCode which are not in tbl_bkp.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Bkp 
WHERE ? */COMBINATION OF ID,Name NOT IN (SELECT COMBINATION OF ID,NAME FROM tbl_NameCode )*/
```

How to compare the combination of two columns with combination of other two?

Comment: whether both the tables have same structure

Comment: yes. Both table has same structure.

Answer (score 5):

If am not wrong [**`Except`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) operator should work.

```
SELECT Id1,Id2,Id3,..Name FROM tbl_Bkp
Except
select Id1,Id2,Id3,..Name from tbl_NameCode
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **LEFT JOIN** to fetch all records from left table and add where condition with checking of null value of second table to find unmatched records of left table

Try this:

```
SELECT NC.ID, NC.Name
FROM tbl_NameCode NC 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_bkp A ON NC.ID = A.ID AND NC.Name = A.Name
WHERE A.ID IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can concat the strings . If your ID is integer then cast it to nvcrchar(50)

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Bkp 
WHERE ID+''+Name NOT IN (SELECT cast(ID as nvarchar(50))+''+NAME FROM tbl_NameCode
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try the following:

```
declare @tbl_NameCode table (id int, name varchar(100))

declare @tbl_Bkp table (id int, name varchar(100))

insert into @tbl_NameCode select 1, 'ABC'
union select 2, 'XYZ'
union select 3, 'PQR'

insert into @tbl_Bkp select 1, 'ABC'
union select 2, 'XXX'
union select 3, 'PQR'

select a.* from @tbl_Bkp a
left join @tbl_NameCode b on convert(varchar, a.id) + a.name = convert(varchar, b.id) + b.name
where b.id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL `EXISTS` will make a good comparison for you. and return the results where they differ. Exists is quite fast and more desirable where you have large record.

```
SELECT ID,Name FROM tbl_Bkp t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID,Name FROM tbl_NameCode WHERE ID=t1.ID AND Name=t1.Name )
```